# gsutil: Can't touch a file with brackets in the name

Tags: cloud, bucket, gsutil

> $ gsutil du -sh gs://test123/
>
> CommandException: Cloud folder gs://test123/testfile[1994]/ contains a wildcard; gsutil does not currently support objects with wildcards in their name.
>
> $ gsutil mv gs://test123/testfile[1994]/ gs://test123/testfile_1994/
>
> CommandException: Cloud folder gs://test123/testfile[1994]/ contains a wildcard; gsutil does not currently support objects with wildcards in their name.
>
> $ gsutil mv "gs://test123/testfile\[1994\]/" gs://test123/testfile_1994/
>
> CommandException: No URLs matched:

I'm unable to list the directory, or rename the folder. What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since there isn't any answers here whatsoever, I'll post what I've done. I haven't put any effort into making this easy to use. YMMV.

1. Check out [gsutil](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gsutil) from GitHub
2. Go back to commit `d153cb33bfa8e96a32b2ebdee86e03251cfb71fd`, which is where I was working at.
3. Revert commit [`46c09952d137e8704c1209bb8bdfbb2e73a2cd5d`](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gsutil/commit/46c09952d137e8704c1209bb8bdfbb2e73a2cd5d) after reading the commit message and making sure you're aware of why this was blocked.
4. Apply the patch at the bottom of this message. It effectively disables `[` and `]` as wildcard characters.

I've also filed [a bug](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gsutil/issues/405) against gsutil to reintroduce support.

Here's the patch:

```
diff --git a/gslib/storage_url.py b/gslib/storage_url.py
index 8f1df95..30308ac 100644
--- a/gslib/storage_url.py
+++ b/gslib/storage_url.py
@@ -35,7 +35,7 @@ S3_VERSION_REGEX = re.compile(r'(?P<object>.+)#(?P<version_id>.+)$')
 # Matches file strings of the form 'file://dir/filename'
 FILE_OBJECT_REGEX = re.compile(r'([^:]*://)(?P<filepath>.*)')
 # Regex to determine if a string contains any wildcards.
-WILDCARD_REGEX = re.compile(r'[*?\[\]]')
+WILDCARD_REGEX = re.compile(r'\*')


 class StorageUrl(object):
diff --git a/gslib/wildcard_iterator.py b/gslib/wildcard_iterator.py
index c3194c2..8cde4df 100644
--- a/gslib/wildcard_iterator.py
+++ b/gslib/wildcard_iterator.py
@@ -202,7 +202,8 @@ class CloudWildcardIterator(WildcardIterator):
           url = StorageUrlFromString(urls_needing_expansion.pop(0))
           (prefix, delimiter, prefix_wildcard, suffix_wildcard) = (
               self._BuildBucketFilterStrings(url.object_name))
-          prog = re.compile(fnmatch.translate(prefix_wildcard))
+          prog = re.compile(fnmatch.translate(
+              prefix_wildcard).replace("[", "\[").replace("]", "\]"))

           # If we have a suffix wildcard, we only care about listing prefixes.
           listing_fields = (
```