# How to download folder containing brackets in name?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, gsutil

I have many folders in Google Cloud Storage that contain square brackets in the name. gsutil sees square brackets as wild cards and I am unable to download the project. Can I download folders another way?

I tried using the escape character and quotes. These do not work.

gsutil cp gs://myBucket/[Projects]Number1 /Volumes/DriveName/Desktop

The result is to download files from Google Cloud Storage to my local computer.

Comment: What do you mean by "These do not work"?  Is there an error message?  What does it actually do?

Comment: Attempting to use quotes and escape characters or do without them leads me to the following error, Failure: Bad Character Range

Answer (score 1):

gsutil doesn't have a way to escape wildcard characters in file / object names. There's an open issue about this: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gsutil/issues/220

Basically, you'll have to use a different tool (or write some code) to handle such files/objects.

Comment: Is this solution worth trying out? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36780004/gsutil-cant-touch-a-file-with-brackets-in-the-name

Comment: You're of course welcome to do that, but: (a) it seems pretty hacky to do a one-off mod that temporarily makes gsutil not support brackets. You then have 2 versions of gsutil, one that does bracket wildcarding and one that doesn't. (b) The GCS team won't support your using a modified gsutil. You can of course do it, but if you have problems you'll be asked to use a released version before they can help you with the problems.